# Prevent sed expanding variables

Tags: php, linux, unix, replace, sed

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `mysql_query($sql)` on an obsolete project.

Executed command line :

```
find services/mobile/phones.php -exec sed -i "s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g" {} \;
```

Expected: `mysqli_query($link,$sql);`

Result: `mysqli_query(,$sql);`

I've trying to fix it myself but this is my defeat letter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Escape the `$` sign

Comment: Prevent variable expansion by using `'` in place of `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that double quotes in `sed` make the variables within it to be expanded. Then, `$link` gets expanded to its value, which apparently is not set.

If you want this not to happen, just use single quotes:

```
$ echo "hello" | sed 's/h/$XXX/'
$XXXello
$ echo "hello" | sed "s/h/$XXX/"
ello
```

In your case:

```
find -name "hello.txt" -exec sed -i.bak 's/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g' {} \;
#                                       ^                                     ^
```

See a little example with just the `sed` part:

```
$ cat hello.txt 
this is mysqli_query($query) blabla
```

With double quotes:

```
$ sed "s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g" hello.txt
this is mysqli_query(,$query) blabla
#                   ^^
#                   unchanged
```

With single quotes:

```
$ sed 's/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g' hello.txt
this is mysqli_query($link,$query) blabla
#                    ^^^^^
#                    changed!
```

Comment: You're right. Tested with single quotes and works like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with `sed`. You're running `sed` from the shell - well, you're running `find` from the shell, and it's turning around and running `sed`. Either way, it's what the shell does to your command line long before `find` or `sed` ever sees it that is causing your problem.  Any command will do, so let's use `echo` since it's easy to see what's going on.

We can try with no quotation marks at all:

```
$ echo s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

That fails because parentheses are special characters to the shell, so you have to do something about those. One option is to escape them individually with backslashes:

```
$ echo s/mysqli_query\(/mysqli_query\($link,/g
s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query(,/g
```

That got us past the syntax error, but now we have a missing $link. That's because the dollar sign is also special - the shell replaces `$link` with the value of that parameter locally in the shell at the time you run the command:

```
$ link=hello
$ echo s/mysqli_query\(/mysqli_query\($link,/g
s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query(hello,/g
```

You can again get around the specialness with a backslash:

```
$ echo s/mysqli_query\(/mysqli_query\(\$link,/g
s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g
```

Since that's a lot of backslashes, it's usually easier to put double-quotes around the whole thing instead:

```
$ echo "s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g"
s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query(,/g
```

Oops. The $link is still missing, because double quotes don't prevent expansion of values via `$`. You can put that backslash back (despite the quotes) to prevent that:

```
$ echo "s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query(\$link,/g"
s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g
```

But usually, the easiest thing to do (at least, when you don't *want* variable substitution in your string) is to use single quotes, which prevent any special character interpretation at all inside them:

```
$ echo 's/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g'
s/mysqli_query(/mysqli_query($link,/g
```

Some commentary unrelated to your question. This command:

```
find services/mobile/phones.php -exec sed -i '...' {} \;
```

... looks like it's just running `sed` on a single file. So why is that wrapped in a `find` command?  You can just run `sed` directly:

```
sed -i '...' services/mobile/phones.php
```

If you are instead running `find` on a directory and *do* want to run the `sed` command on multiple files, it would be more efficient to replace the `\;` on the end with a `+`. That tells `find` that the command you're running will still work if you pass it more than one file at a time.